# Airport baggage vocabulary

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

On a recent trip to a Spanish-speaking country, I realized I don't know most of the terms involved in the process of retrieving luggage at a destination airport. I thought it would make sense to combine them in one question. What are the typical Spanish translations for:

- baggage claim
- baggage carousel
- conveyer belt
- oversize baggage
- overweight baggage
- checked baggage
- carry-on baggage
- baggage cart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- baggage claim: Zona de recogida de equipajes
- baggage carousel: Cinta transportadora de equipajes.
- conveyer belt: Cinta transportadora.
- oversize baggage: Equipaje con exceso de tamaño.
- overweight baggage: Equipaje con exceso de peso. Equipaje con sobrepeso.
- checked baggage: Equipaje facturado.
- carry-on baggage: Equipaje de mano.
- baggage cart: Carrito de equipaje. Carrito para equipaje.